# Collecting multiple properties to a Map using a single Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an Userdefined Object which contains multiple properties. As they all have same datatype as `String`, I wanted to use Streams to collect all those properties values into a `Map`. I am not aware that `Collectors.toMap()` or `Collectors.groupingBy()` is able to serve this.

```
public class TeamMates{

    private String playerFirstName;
    private String playerLastName;
    private String playerMaidenName;

    //Constructors , getters and Setters    
}
```

I have an `List<TeamMates>` object which I wanted to use it to stream and collect it into a `Map<String,List<String>>`.

I wanted the Map to contain

```
(playerFirstName,("John","Bob"));
(playerLastName,("Joe","Henry"));
(playerMaidenName,("H","K"));
```

As I don't wanted to use streaming multiple times to collect each property individually or using `forEach`, is there any way to get the above properties with a single stream.

Comment: You could probably do it with a `flatMap` and `groupingBy` combined, but honestly your code is going to be much harder to follow than a loop, and it won't be any more efficient.

Comment: It's not clear what that output means as a Map. Can you show what the instances of `TeamMates` looks like as input, to get that output? Does one Map entry correspond to one `TeamMates`. Are those map keys supposed to be literal strings, e.g. "playerFirstName" rather than `playerFirstName`?

Comment: I wanted the result outputMap which contains the POJO Variables as keys and the associated variable instance data as values for the Map.I expect only 3 map entries - playerFirstName, playerLastName , playerMaidenName as Keys , whereas the associated instance variables should be present as the values for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a map of the value generating getter methods and their respective field names.

```java
// Map.of is available from Java 9. 
// If you are using java 8 you could create the below using a normal HashMap.
Map<String, Function<TeamMates, String>> mapper 
    = Map.of("playerFirstName", TeamMates::getPlayerFirstName,
             "playerLastName", TeamMates::getPlayerLastName,
             "playerMaidenName", TeamMates::getPlayerMaidenName);
```

Now iterate this mapper function and apply each mapping to the list of teammates

```java
// applies getter method on each teammate object and returns the list of strings.
Function<Function<TeamMates, String>, List<String>> listMapper 
    = fn -> list.stream().map(fn::apply).collect(Collectors.toList());

// assume static import of Collectors.toMap
Map<String, List<String>> map = mapper.entrySet().stream()
                                      .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey,
                                                     e -> listMapper.apply(e.getValue())));
```

I would also suggest naming your class as `TeamMate` instead of `TeamMates` as the class represents a single team mate entity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

- An instance of `TeamMates` holds the information of one person (should it be called `TeamMate`?)
- The keys of the output Map are the literal strings `"playerFirstName"`, `"playerLastName"`, `"playerMaidenName"` (rather than how they appear as variables in the question)
- The intention is to collect e.g. all of the first names of the objects in the input `List` into the `List` corresponding to the `"playerFirstName"` key in the output `Map`

Then:

The main complexity with streaming from the initial `List` to the resulting `Map`, is that the `Map` entries don't correspond to the `List` elements.

Here's one way to do it, using [Stream.collect(Supplier supplier, BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator, BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) variety of the collect method. See the `main` method in the below example. Since the arguments are all functions, I've extracted them out to variables to make the stream pipeline easier to read, and also to show the types of each function:

```java
public class TeamMate {

    private static final String PLAYER_MAIDEN_NAME = "playerMaidenName";
    private static final String PLAYER_LAST_NAME = "playerLastName";
    private static final String PLAYER_FIRST_NAME = "playerFirstName";

    /**
     * Passed to Stream::collect, extracted out to show type
     */
    private static final Supplier<Map<String, List<String>>> supplier = () -> Map.of(
            PLAYER_FIRST_NAME, new ArrayList<String>(),
            PLAYER_LAST_NAME, new ArrayList<String>(),
            PLAYER_MAIDEN_NAME, new ArrayList<String>());

    /**
     * Passed to Stream::collect, extracted out to show type
     */
    private static final BiConsumer<Map<String, List<String>>, TeamMate> accumulator = (r, tm) -> {
        r.get(PLAYER_FIRST_NAME).add(tm.getPlayerFirstName());
        r.get(PLAYER_LAST_NAME).add(tm.getPlayerLastName());
        r.get(PLAYER_MAIDEN_NAME).add(tm.getPlayerMaidenName());
    };

    /**
     * Passed to Stream::collect, extracted out to show type
     */
    private static final BiConsumer<Map<String, List<String>>, Map<String, List<String>>> combiner = (x, y) -> {
        x.get(PLAYER_FIRST_NAME).addAll(y.get(PLAYER_FIRST_NAME));
        x.get(PLAYER_LAST_NAME).addAll(y.get(PLAYER_LAST_NAME));
        x.get(PLAYER_MAIDEN_NAME).addAll(y.get(PLAYER_MAIDEN_NAME));
    };

    private String playerFirstName;
    private String playerLastName;
    private String playerMaidenName;

    TeamMate(String playerFirstName, String playerLastName, String playerMaidenName) {
        this.playerFirstName = playerFirstName;
        this.playerLastName = playerLastName;
        this.playerMaidenName = playerMaidenName;
    }

    // getters & setters...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // input list
        List<TeamMate> teamMates = List.of(new TeamMate("John", "Joe", "H"), new TeamMate("Bob", "Henry", "K"));

        // single stream, as desired
        Map<String, List<String>> output = teamMates.stream().collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner);

        // output map
        System.out.println(output);

        // demonstration that results are as expected
        assert output.containsKey(PLAYER_FIRST_NAME);
        assert output.containsKey(PLAYER_LAST_NAME);
        assert output.containsKey(PLAYER_MAIDEN_NAME);

        assert output.get(PLAYER_FIRST_NAME).containsAll(teamMates.stream().map(TeamMate::getPlayerFirstName).toList());
        assert output.get(PLAYER_LAST_NAME).containsAll(teamMates.stream().map(TeamMate::getPlayerLastName).toList());
        assert output.get(PLAYER_MAIDEN_NAME).containsAll(teamMates.stream().map(TeamMate::getPlayerMaidenName).toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Both the answers seems to be correct, but the other solution seems to be simple , so choosing different answer.Thanks. !!!